# How to see which line while parsing json source caused the exception?

Tags: parsing, line-numbers, nlohmann-json

I have JSON files with hundreds of lines, but when there is an error that causes a parsing exception, the library returns a character position, not a line number.

Line number would be hugely helpful since most text editors will show you, or take you to the line number, but I don't know of any that give the absolute character number.

I found the spot in parse_error where deserialization member byte_ holds the character index, but it doesn't seem to have line number info.

Does the json container "know" which line it is, and I could ask for it in the exception handler? I know this isn't a trivial issue, since different OS's give us the "joys" of different EOLs, but perhaps it has been handled anyway?

Comment: checn the [validator for json](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

Comment: If you have Gnu command-line utilities handy, `head -c NNN | wc -l` will tell you which line contains byte number NNN.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `dd` command with the `bs=` option to specify the number of bytes.